# Как вызвать родительский метод из тела перегруженного в С++?

Tags: c++, ооп, функции

Есть класс.
У него есть другой класс-наследник.
В нём перегружается родительский метод.

Мне нужно из перегруженного метода наследника, вызвать метод родителя.

Как это сделать?

```
class Foo{
 public:
    void example(){
        // Код родителя
    }
};

class Bar : public Foo{
 public:
    void example(){
        // Тут должен выполнится код родителя
        // А тут - код наследника
    }
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Можете сделать это следующим образом

```
void example(){
    Foo::example();
    // А тут - код наследника
}
```

или так

```
void example(){
    this->Foo::example();
    // А тут - код наследника
}
```

или (при условии, что метод не является виртуальным), например, так

```
void example(){
    static_cast<Foo *>( this )->example();
    // А тут - код наследника
}
```

Так как метод, объявленный в производном классе, скрывает одноименный метод в родительском классе, то следует использовать квалифицированное имя метода родительского класса.

Comment: А разве это сработает, если метод не статический?

Comment: @JaminPeru, да.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо, действительно работает. Благодарю.

Comment: @JaminPeru, ответ прими нажатием на галочку.

Comment: @JaminPeru  Данный метод вызывается для текущего объекта из нестатического метода объекта.

Comment: @Qwertiy говорит только через 10 минут. Приму позже.

Comment: Имеет смысл добавить, что второй вариант не будет работать, если `example` будет виртуальной.